# How to secure different Spring Boot rest APIs Using OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I want to secure different Spring boot rest APIs using OAuth2 authorization server.

What is the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: please add more information and what you have tried ?

Comment: What do you mean by share "oauth2 server"? Do you want other services authenticate using oauth2 server?

Comment: in other words separating oauth2 authoriazation server and rest api endpoints.Normally we have spring controller and AuthorizationServerConfig ResourceServerConfig in same project , i want to put controller in a different project rather than same project